# How to create infinite interval Observable that will emit new Object every time interval?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to create an Observable that will emit new object every second.
So for now i am just zipping one Observable, which emits finite number of objects from a list, with interval Observable.

```
   val list1 = mutableListOf<SomeClass1>(
            SomeClass1("1", 1), SomeClass1("2", 2), SomeClass1("3", 3),
            SomeClass1("4", 4), SomeClass1("5", 5), SomeClass1("6", 6),
            SomeClass1("7", 7), SomeClass1("8", 8), SomeClass1("9", 9)
    )

    val someClass1Observable = Observable
            .fromIterable(list1)
            .zipWith(Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                    BiFunction { item: SomeClass1, _: Long -> item })
```

So how to actually make this infinite, in a way that every 2 second there will be emiited new object of class SomeClass1 with some parameters?

Comment: How do you determine the actual values of the `n`th `SomeClass1` object? Does it depend only on the value of `n`, i. e. on its position in the stream? Does it depend on the previously emitted items?

Comment: @david.mihola check my answer if you are interested what was my intention

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for my question, that satisfies my:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var counter = 0

    val periodicSomeClass1 = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(
                    {
                        counter++
                        Observable.just(SomeClass1("$counter", counter))
                    }
            )


    periodicSomeClass1.subscribe { t: SomeClass1 -> Log.v("periodicSomeClass1", t.toString())  }

}
```

Comment: OK, in this case, I would change the answer to: `Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map({SomeClass("$it", it)})`. That's because interval emits consecutive integers, starting with 0 - you don't need any external mutable state. Also, `flatMap` with only a `just` inside is practically never needed, just use `map` in this case.

Comment: @david.mihola Thanks, do you think this cause the problem with my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368711/why-i-have-undesired-log-output-when-merging-2-observables-into-one ?