# Why i have undesired Log output when merging 2 observables into other Observable, which buffers them every 10 seconds

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to simulate merging 2 different Observable streams, which are emitting some object every second. This object has the same Parent in those 2 streams.

I thought, that in the console will appear new object with value after 1 second.
However, when i print those objects, i get objects that skipped the previous emission. So like object with value 1, 3, 5, 7 etc.

However, in the buffer, which merges those two it seems that it only buffer the 2, 4, 6, 8 etc. emissions.

Here is my code:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var counter = 0
    var counter2 = 0


    val periodicSomeClass1 = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(
                    {
                        counter++
                        Observable.just(SomeClass1("$counter", counter))
                    }
            )

    val periodicSomeClass2 = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(
                    {
                        counter2++
                        Observable.just(SomeClass2(counter2.toDouble()))
                    }
            )

    periodicSomeClass1.subscribe { t: SomeClass1 -> Log.v("periodicSomeClass1", t.toString())  }
    periodicSomeClass2.subscribe { t: SomeClass2 -> Log.v("periodicSomeClass2", t.toString())  }


    Observable.merge(periodicSomeClass1, periodicSomeClass2)
            .buffer(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .doOnSubscribe { Log.v("bufferObservable", "STARTED") }
            .subscribe { t: MutableList<Parent> ->
                Log.v("bufferObservable", "onNext")
                t.forEach { Log.v("onNext", it.toString()) }
            }
}
```

And here is what i have in the Log output with first buffer/merge emsission:

```
 V/periodicSomeClass1: SomeClass1(a=1, b=1)
 V/periodicSomeClass2: SomeClass2(a=1.0)
 V/periodicSomeClass1: SomeClass1(a=3, b=3)
 V/periodicSomeClass2: SomeClass2(a=3.0)
 V/periodicSomeClass1: SomeClass1(a=5, b=5)
 V/periodicSomeClass2: SomeClass2(a=5.0)
 V/periodicSomeClass1: SomeClass1(a=7, b=7)
 V/periodicSomeClass2: SomeClass2(a=7.0)
 V/periodicSomeClass1: SomeClass1(a=9, b=9)
 V/periodicSomeClass2: SomeClass2(a=9.0)
 V/periodicSomeClass1: SomeClass1(a=11, b=11)
 V/periodicSomeClass2: SomeClass2(a=11.0)
 V/periodicSomeClass1: SomeClass1(a=13, b=13)
 V/periodicSomeClass2: SomeClass2(a=13.0)
 V/periodicSomeClass1: SomeClass1(a=15, b=15)
 V/periodicSomeClass2: SomeClass2(a=15.0)
 V/periodicSomeClass1: SomeClass1(a=17, b=17)
 V/periodicSomeClass2: SomeClass2(a=17.0)
 V/periodicSomeClass1: SomeClass1(a=19, b=19)
 V/periodicSomeClass2: SomeClass2(a=19.0)
 V/bufferObservable: onNext
 V/onNext: SomeClass1(a=2, b=2)
 V/onNext: SomeClass2(a=2.0)
 V/onNext: SomeClass1(a=4, b=4)
 V/onNext: SomeClass2(a=4.0)
 V/onNext: SomeClass1(a=6, b=6)
 V/onNext: SomeClass2(a=6.0)
 V/onNext: SomeClass1(a=8, b=8)
 V/onNext: SomeClass2(a=8.0)
 V/onNext: SomeClass1(a=10, b=10)
 V/onNext: SomeClass2(a=10.0)
 V/onNext: SomeClass1(a=12, b=12)
 V/onNext: SomeClass2(a=12.0)
 V/onNext: SomeClass1(a=14, b=14)
 V/onNext: SomeClass2(a=14.0)
 V/onNext: SomeClass1(a=16, b=16)
 V/onNext: SomeClass2(a=16.0)
 V/onNext: SomeClass1(a=18, b=18)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like you correctly suspected in [the comment on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47368625/763935), this problem is indeed related.

1.) You are subscribing twice to both of your source observables, once directly for each of them and once through the subscription to the `merge`d Observable.

2.) So you then have four Observables running in total, where two of them are incrementing (and reading from) `counter` and the other two are incrementing (and reading from) `counter2`.

3.) For each of these pairs the two intervals are ever so slightly offset and each `flatMap` from the first of each pair sees the value `n`, increments it to `n+1` and prints it. Then shortly afterwards, the other instance comes along and sees `n+1`, increments to `n+2`, prints that, etc.

Finally, the `buffer` hides that all of this happens interleaved because it prints all the even values after all the odd ones.

Any solution really depends on what you want to achieve - is this just a playground example, or does it model some real problem?

Comment: Thanks, i am trying to model solution for situtation like this, that i have 2 other reactive repositories which provides me Observable object of the same parent and i need to merge/buffer them and do something with them every 10 seconds or so. I do this to prevent multiple calls to db or so. Those 2 reactive repositories will be connectableObservables, which i will start to listen to it. Can you provide me the correct answer if you know how to achive this? So this is a playground on which i will be based my other same situtation.

Comment: I want to base on my question solution, want to use that merge operator which buffers them every 10 seconds. Those 2 streams that i need to connect will be connectableObserables, to be specific those are 2 repositories that one delivers me Observable<Location> and other some other object, they have the same Parent class.

Comment: So i guess i need to remove invoking subscribe on them, and just subscribe once in my zip/buffer Observable. Then it will work as i expect i guess

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it. If you do need multiple subscribers for each source, you could add `.share()` at the end of the defintion of both `periodicSomeClass1` and `periodicSomeClass2`.